# Is it possible to apply Sharding to Mongo DB after deployment with replica set?

Tags: mongodb, deployment, sharding

I have Mongo DB with two replica set. Is it possible to shard these replica set.

Comment: What do you mean by "after deployment"? Deploying a database or an application with the database? Please explain little bit.

Comment: deploying application as well database

Comment: You have already deployed a MongoDB based application, and thinking of sharding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharding is about distributing data among servers called as shards. Sharding is enabled on a database, but collection(s) is/are sharded (a shard cluster can have sharded and unsharded collections). A replica-set can become a shard, within a shard cluster.

So, two replica-sets can become two shards in a shard cluster. Still, you have to enable sharding on a database and shard the collections you want to.

The main components in shard cluster are:

- mongos: A router process to route your application queries to the appropriate shards.
- Config server: A configuration server to maintain metatdata of the shard cluster and sharded data; this is to be a replica-set.
- Shards: Replica-sets, each as a shard; these have the database data.

These components need to be configured first; the shard replica-sets to be used in a shard cluster, the config server replica-set and the mongos process. Then sharding is to be enabled on the database (on the replica-set).

For example, you have a database called as 'receivables' with collections `customers` and`invoices` on one of the two replica-sets. You choose to shard the customer collection only. When the customer collection is sharded, the customers data is distributed among the two shards, based on a defined shard key. Defining a shard key is part of the process of sharding a collection.

In fact deciding on which field is going to be the shard key is one of the most important aspects of sharding. This determines how effectively: (i) the queries are going to be, (ii) the data is going to be distributed evenly among the shards,  and (iii) the future scaling with added shards to the cluster.

Shard key is important. This field on the collection must be immutable and also the values must be immutable. All the documents in the collection must have the shard key field.

If you already have a running application (with MongoDB database)  and planning to shard the database, an important consideration: what is the shard key going to be and how it will affect the present application (the existing queries). Sharding is not just about distributing data among more servers, it is also about designing aspects of the application and its data.

*Useful Links:*

- [Convert a Replica Set to a Sharded
  Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/index.html)
- [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/index.html)

Comment: if  I  already have replica set what are the steps that i need to migrate to sharded cluster

Comment: I am reading this is multiple places. but this does not give me any steps to migrate.I need to complete this task in one week bro . Please help me bro

Comment: As I have mentioned, if you have a replica-set and a database you can setup a sharded cluster. What collections you want to shard is upto your requirements. Here is some documentation which shows steps to [deploy a shard cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/index.html).

Comment: I also added link to the post from MongoDB documentation on "converting replica-set to sharded cluster".

Comment: bro how does it affects my current deployment. how much down time does this take

Comment: I don't know how much downtime it might take in your setup. Some careful planning is required, first (you have adequate documentation, now). I am assuming you have good knowledge of your existing deployment. Once, you have a clear plan and steps, first deploy in a test environment and see how it goes. It will give some idea about how much time it might take and also highlights any issues that might arise. It will also validate your plan and steps. [Continued in following comment...]

Comment: Configuring the mongos and config servers won't affect your current deployment or application. But, enabling sharding with the replica-sets will. How much time it takes depends upon the size of the data you are trying to shard. Configuring the replica-sets as shards can happen in rolling upgrade on each node of the replica-sets - one server at a time. Enabling sharding on the database and sharding the collection - these will depend upon the amount of data, I think.